# How to find out child tables for a given table

Tags: java, sql-server, ibatis

I have a table  'A ' in MSSQL. It is the parent table for many other tables. there are about atleast 200 tables depending on this table. ( These 200 tables have foreign key references to 'A'. I thought all 200 tables have on-delete -cascade clause with table 'A' .
 There is a query in my application which deletes records from 'A' based on two parameters in 'WHERE' Clause. But It is throwing Caused by:

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint

Now I realize that not all tables are connected with 'ON DELETE CASCADE' WITH TABLE 'A'. It is tedious to see all tables having foreign key references to table 'A' or ON DELETE CASCADE link to Table 'A'.

Is there a short cut to know all dependencies, instead of generating DDL's of all tables and see.

Thanks  in advance

Comment: You could write a query against the [information schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186778.aspx) that returns non-cascading FKeys to Table A.

Answer (score 1):

Use this SQL

```
sp_help 'YourTableNameHere'
```

The full details on this can be found here:  [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187335.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

You can use one of several free database diagramming tools (Google is your friend here) or you can create a Database Diagram from within SSMS.  These are held within each database.  Simply add the tables you want to see and it will map the relationships for you automatically.

If you need, detailed steps can be found [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1816/getting-started-with-sql-server-database-diagrams/).